# Loading Windows 7 on external drive for gaming

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, windows

I'm attempting to load Windows 7 onto an external hard drive in order to boot from the hard drive whenever I play games. I originally split my internal drive to make a Mac OS side and a Windows side, but both sides quickly ran out of room and performance suffered.

In summation, I want to host the windows machine on the external drive, instead of the internal one. I have tried several tutorials, but none have proved successful. The most successful was this one (http://bleeptobleep.blogspot.com/2013/02/mac-install-windows-7-or-8-on-external.html) but my computer did not offer my external drive as an option to boot from when I restarted.

I have:

Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5

Seagate Backup Plus Portable Drive (1TB)

Access to a Windows Vista PC if that helps

Comment: Do you mean a bootable Windows or "virtual windows machine"

Comment: Since the link he provided is for Bootcamp, I presume the word "virtual" is a mistake...

Comment: I'm sorry, "virtual" is a mistake. I was misinformed as to the correct terminology. I need to boot from an external drive that runs windows.